# Understanding PCA plot built on data normalized by two normalization methods

Tags: pca, normalization, dimensionality-reduction, large-data

[image]

I tried two different normalization methods, generated the PCA plot above on the combined data, and colored the samples by the normalization type. Both normalization methods should give similar results for a standard dataset (proteomics). By looking at the plot, it looks like the overall shapes are the same. However, I am not able to figure out what the separation in PC1 is linked to. The PCA was done on the expression value of 7,289 proteins for around 405 samples.

Any suggestions for understanding this plot would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Is it an artifact of the scaling of the x-axis? In other words, the green component is shifted farther left of the orange component with neither one centering on zero.

Comment: Is there a way to check the scaling artifact or rectify it?

Comment: Create two separate scatterplots. Do they conform to expectations wrt normalization?